# Access enum written in Objective C from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm integrating [MAImagePickerController](https://github.com/mmackh/MAImagePickerController-of-InstaPDF) (written in Objective-C) in my Swift project. The integration of the library is OK and I can build the project. However, When using, I couldn't set property `sourceType` of `MAImagePickerController`. Following is the code in Swift:

```
let imagePicker:MAImagePickerController = MAImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.sourceType = .MAImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
```

And it shows the error:

> Type 'UnsafeMutablePointer has no
>   member 'MAImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera'

Following is the declaration of enum type `MAImagePickerControllerSourceType`

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MAImagePickerControllerSourceType)
{
    MAImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
    MAImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary
};
```

And this is how they use it in Objective-C:

```
MAImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[MAImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[imagePicker setSourceType:MAImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
```

For Swift code, I didn't use method `setSourceType` because it refers to the default `sourceType` of UIImagePickerView.

Answer (score 1):

Based on vadian's suggestion and my observation, following is the solution:
- Step 1: Change property sourceType to normal enum type (not pointer - remove asterisk character

```
@property MAImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType;
```

- Step 2: Use vadian's answer

```
imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
```

And it just works.

Answer (score 0):

When transfering ObjC enums to Swift usually the whole type prefix is omitted.

```
imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
```

Comment: One thing that I noticed is that the property sourceType is declared as a pointer:
`@property MAImagePickerControllerSourceType *sourceType;`
I don't know if it causes the problem in Swift

Comment: Yes, that's probably the reason. The enum is used as a pointer.